# For loop to create multiple dataframe

Tags: r

I have several dataframe, named "df.1","df.2",.....until "df.100".

I want to create a new dataframe for each of them, such as:

```
df.1.new <- df.1  %>% filter (var.1>=100)  %>% group_by (var.2)  %>% slice (which.min(var.3))
```

How can I apply the code to all thses dataframe from "df.1" to "df.100"?

Answer (score 2):

Get the dataframes in a list  and apply the code to each list element.

```
library(dplyr)

purrr::map(mget(paste0('df.', 1:100)), function(data) {
  data  %>% filter(var.1>=100)  %>% group_by(var.2)  %>% slice(which.min(var.3))
}) -> result
```